# Best practices on Angular and Nodejs using same code repository & publishing in the same server

Tags: node.js, angular, server, repository, publish

In 2020 - is it a good practice to have both Nodejs based APIs/Services and Angular frontend code deploy in the same server? Can we also have the Angular Code & nodejs code in the same code repository.

Answer (score 0):

Every implementation depends on the usecase,

If your application is small and you see it not going to have many features you can go with monolithic approach (all Backend and Frontend together)

Else you can go with a microservice-based approach.

If you are not sure of anything use Docker-based containers for frontend and backend respectively on the same server for starting with, with this approach you can easily scale or move to microservices if required. This will cover the separation of concerns.